# Typescript d.ts

Tags: node.js, typescript

I can't seem to grasp what is this actually about.

how can I create typings for this basic library? https://github.com/deanilvincent/check-password-strength/blob/master/index.js

This is what i've got so far:

```js
declare module 'check-password-strength' {

    function check_password_strength(password:any): any;
    export = check_password_strength;
}
```

But how does it work? The Library is called check-password-strength. How is it possible, when I create function with check_password_strength, to still work? (Yes, this code actually works.)
I use it like this:

```js
import check_password_strength from 'check-password-strength'

check_password_strength(body.password)
```

The problem is, except that I don't get why is it working with _ instead of - (- is not working though) I can't make functions with -. How does typescript know, that it should call the function? The next question I have, how can I change my d.ts file above to actually give me the right return type (for intellisense).

It returns tuple which looks like this:

```
    strength = {
      id: 2,
      value: 'Strong'
    }
```

How can I implement it in my code above?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution randomly for my question number 2. I still don't know however, how is it possible for typescript to call check-password-strength , when I use _.

The answer is:

```js
function check_password_strength(password:any): {id: number, value: string};
```